# Use one elasticsearch query to link two indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indices in elastic, index_a and index_b, a sample record in index a looks like below

```
"id": "8",
"name": "pepsi",
"id_b": "13",
```

and sample record in index b looks like

```
"id": "13",
"mapping": "15"
```

While searching I will be provided the name from index a for example `"pepsi"`. I will have to return the mapping field from index b i.e. `"15"`. I know that this can be easily done with two search queries, one where in i return all the `"id_b"` which match the input text from index_a and then the second query will match the id_b from result of first query with index of index_b and returns the mapping `"15"`. My question is can this be done in one query.

Answer (score -1):

I did this code and the response has mapping value. Reference: [article](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/search-apis/lookup-runtime-fields/).

```
POST index_a/_doc?refresh
{
  "id": "8",
  "name": "pepsi",
  "id_b": "13"
}

PUT index_b/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "id": "13",
  "mapping": 15
}

POST index_a/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "pepsi"
    }
  }, 
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "mapping": {
        "type": "lookup", 
        "target_index": "index_b", 
        "input_field": "id_b", 
        "target_field": "id", 
        "fetch_fields": ["mapping"] 
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "mapping"
  ],
  "_source": false
}
```

Response:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "index_a",
    "_id": "n3YLnYYB_18wwUoiAnA5",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "fields": {
      "mapping": [
        {
          "mapping": [
            15
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: i don't think this is the answer, this maps all documents between the two indices. In my case it should return the specific mapping from index b where in index a's name is pepsi